# Como obtener diferentes id de cada dato de un webservice? ANDROID-STUDIO

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola buenas nuevamente.

Estoy con un proyecto donde se va a mostrar desde un webservice un top ten de las canciones mas sonadas justo en ese momento, el problema es que ademas de eso, hay que dejar el detalle de cada cancion, que dentro del webservice es un id, yo se obtener el id con postman, el problema es que no se como hacer la llamada a la URL y despues que me da la lista de las 10 canciones, donde hacer la llamada a los diferentes id. 
API:
https://itunes.apple.com/es/rss/topsongs/limit=10/json

y luego en algun momento de cada cancion hay un id que es quien tiene todos los detalles de cada cancion, si alguien me puede ayudar, lo agradeceria mucho.

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que te devuelve el enlace ese que has puesto es directamente un JSON con todos los detalles del TOP 10 de canciones, es decir en ese JSON tienes todo lo que necesitas, solo que tienes que interpretarlo.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, Tu quieres consumir un webservice de la api que proporcionas y no sabes como consumirlo? @kronosXXI tiene razon, la url que proporcionas ya te trae todo los datos que supuestamente necesitas. Para consumir web services puedes usar la libreria de Spring que es muy estable y confiable. Aqui hay un tutorial para integrar Spring a AndroidStudio (es sumamente facil) https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/